# How to change values of one column using other column's values from a different file

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

I don't know what command should I use in unix.

Let say I have a file like this:

```
A  23
B  52
C  36
F  25
```

and second file with 3 columns:

```
A  aligator  2
B  panda  3
C  bear  4
D  pig  1
E  yeti  0
F  shark  9
G  dog  10
H  cat  1
```

Now I would like to replace first column values (in  1 file) using the second column values (2 file) if the values from the first columns match between files

example of output:

```
aligator  23
panda  52
bear  36
shark  25
```

Can anyone help me?

best.

Answer (score 3):

If the files are sorted, you can use `join` from coreutils:

```
join -o '2.2 1.2' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
aligator 23
panda 52
bear 36
shark 25
```

Answer (score 1):

The `awk` is a good tool for this job:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}a[$1]{print $2,a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

When first file is being read (`FN==FNR`) fill array `a` with values from second column and indexed from first column. Then, when second file is processed print its second column and second column from file1.

Output:

```
aligator 23
panda 52
bear 36
shark 25
```